# Grabbing an image from an HTTP response with C#

Tags: c#, javascript, html, http, rest

I'm trying to grab an image from an HTTP response in C#, but instead of an image, it's one of those redirects. Here's the relevant code:

```
String url = "my image URL that's actually a redirect URL"
Image img = null;
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    using (Stream str = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        img = Image.FromStream(str);
    }
}
```

However, it keeps telling me that I can't seek through response. I saved the response stream in a byte[] and then printed it out, and it turns out the response stream is actually of the redirect page, not of the image itself, and that the browser is taking care that via Javascript.

How should I go about catching this image if it's never actually transmitted as a response to my initial request? I don't know how to monitor my browser's subsequent requests, and even if I point the stream at the image URL that it redirects to, it still gives me the same problems and prints out the same redirect page HTML.

Edit: This is the Javascript page that's being loaded (instead of the image) (there's also the standard   stuff, but this is the only script on the page):

```
<script>
var escapedHash = '';
var url = 'https://login.salesforce.com/?ec=302&startURL=%2Fcontent%2Fsession%3Furl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fc.na9.content.force.com%252Fprofilephoto%252F005%252FF';
if (window.location.hash) {
   escapedHash = '%23' + window.location.hash.slice(1);
}
if (window.location.replace){ 
window.location.replace(url + escapedHash);
} else {;
window.location.href = url + escapedHash;
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Why not check the js and do the logic in there in you application?

Comment: I tried manually copying the URL from the JS into my app just to see if that would work, but it still acts as a redirect, and the contents of the HTTP response still contain the Javascript page. :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some sites take steps to prevent people from using their hosted images.  Basically you have to claim that the requesting site (referring URL) is on their domain.

What happens if you use the same link your browser used?  If you right click on the image can you "Copy Image URL" or view the "Properties"?  If so, what happens if you copy the URL into a new browser window?  What happens if you use the URL from the new browser window (showing the image) as the URL you are trying to download?

In my experience redirects are handled by the browser and by the .NET classes without issue.  You might have to specify an argument or set a property to automatically follow redirects though.

Is it possible to get the URL you are trying to download?

**Update**:
Where does your desktop app log in?  The site does not allow me direct access to the image because I am not logged in.  This would be a problem for your application too.

Your app is not logged in, which is why you are getting the redirect to the log in page.

Comment: I've tried all of the above, and I cannot ever reach a link that ends in .JPG or .PNG (the actual image itself). Even the link that the Javascript points to is extensionless and a redirect in itself. When I copy URL on that image, I get the original Javascript redirect page; I had to open up the Javascript to see the actual URL - which was extensionless thing I'm talking about. When I visit that  extensionless page, copying the image URL gives me that extensionless URL, which is still unusable by my code. So to answer your question, I don't think it's possible to get the direct image URL.

Comment: My app authenticates with OpenAuth, so everything is already OK as far as the server permissions are concerned. You can assume I have access to all the resources I mentioned, the user must be logged in and authenticated for any of this code to execute.

Comment: @TheDramaLlama Can you post the redirect page you are getting?

Comment: That Javascript is the redirect page. The image that you can't access (the target of the redirect) is an extensionless URL that displays the image but is still not compatible with C# streams. That target does not have any page source - it is just an image as far as my browser is concerned, just without an extension (server redirect or something?).

Comment: @TheDramaLlama what is the URL of the HTML where you get the original image source?

Comment: What do you mean by the original image source? That's what I can't find, haha. The "first" URL supplied to me was "https://c.na9.content.force.com/profilephoto/005/F" which is an HTML page containing that Javascript redirect (that you probably can't access). The "second" URL I found was the embedded image URL in that Javascript redirect, but that second URL is some sort of extensionless server redirect that my browser treats like an image but C#'s stream doesn't. The URL that I want to find is the raw .PNG URL of the image, but I don't think that's ever exposed anywhere.

Comment: @TheDramaLlama So that should be the URL for the image.  Do you have a URL to an album page or a page on their site which links/shows this image?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11342/discussion-between-thedramallama-and-trisped)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the root of the problem was just me being dumb. The code works perfectly fine, I just forgot that I had commented out the OpenAuth authentication function earlier to debug.

So the problem was that all of these image requests were being sent with no OAuth header, which caused the server to return a "Log In" page instead of the image (which obviously couldn't be read into a C# Image).

Moral of the story: Make sure you authenticate every request you send.

Comment: Are you going to accept my answer?  It was correct before we started chatting "_Update:
Where does your desktop app log in? The site does not allow me direct access to the image because I am not logged in. This would be a problem for your application too._"

Comment: Ah, you are correct indeed - that was the catalyst that made me realize I had forgotten to un-un-authenticate. Accepted. :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to follow the redirect in the first request (identified by HTTP status 301 and the  header Transport in the response). You can then use your current approach on the response from the redirect location.

Comment: Tried that, but the response from the redirect location is an extensionless redirect itself, and is still not an actual .JPG or .PNG image. I feel like I'm tumbling down a rabbit hole. :(

Comment: You shouldn't mind the extension. The mime type is what counts with regards to the display in the browser. You should continue to follow whatever you get until you get a HTTP response 200. If you encounter 401 you need to provide credentials. 404 is not found, ie a dead end. I would encourage you to read the status code definitions found here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html
PS: while image

Comment: Normally I wouldn't mind the extension, but in this case, my C# stream still couldn't read it, so I opened up the HTTP response myself to see what exactly it contained. Turns out it contained the previous Javascript redirect page (which redirects to the current extensionless page). Circular loop, never gets anywhere, no actual image link to be found anywhere. :(

Comment: Sorry to dissapoint you, but the problem is the authentication mechanism at SalesForce. You will need to read up on http authentication (digest or others) and you will need to put some more work into this. Basically authentication involves putting some secret in the authentication header or a cookie. But obtaining this info can be difficult. You should ask questions about authentication against Salesforce or more general. But in general it is probably advisible to familiarize yourself further with the http protocol.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean - my client is already authenticated with OpenAuth and can access all other data on the site. The only problem I'm having is figuring out how to successfully serialize avatar images - I have no issues accessing any other data. I'm currently already including the OpenAuth access token in the header of all HTTP requests - is there another authentication method I'm missing? (Edit: Correction, I'm an idiot. I commented out my authentication call earlier to debug and forgot to uncomment it. I've been sending all these image downloads with no OAuth header.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11344/discussion-between-faester-and-thedramallama)